# Submit get variable from url

Tags: php, mysql

I have two get variables in the url bar.  I would like to take those variables and put them in a mysql database along with some other data.  For some reason `$data=$_GET[data]` isnt working when i insert its value into a database.  Is this the wrong way to take a get variable already set in the url bar? I have made sure that the get variable is already set and not null.

I think this may be the wrong way to pull down info from the url bar.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your code. Specifically the `INSERT` statement;

Answer (score 0):

Can you post entire url, because sometimes the problem is there. Other than that, try with `$data=$_GET["data"]`

Comment: Minus the last part, this really isn't an answer. But a comment on the original question, which you should post above.

Comment: @jason i think i found the problem.  when i refresh the page by clicking submit the get variables disappear because my action doenst include them.  could this be the reason?

Comment: @user802370 is your form method is "post"? if that's true, than update it to be get, or update your other part of the script to work with post values instead of get.